# Speech recognition in a hybrid mobile app?

Tags: mobile, speech, hybrid

I'm looking to build a cross platform app, ideally using an HTML5 framework such as Trigger.io. However, I'm wondering what would be the best way to implement speech recognition. According to my research most HTML5 speech recognition systems only work on Chrome so that's not really an option. Is there a way to build this using native modules? If not on Trigger.io, is this supported in other frameworks?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried PhoneGap.It has certain native capabilities exposed through there api and for the things which are not there you can always code in native and use as plugin with phone gap.

Comment: I have - however I find it quite buggy. :( Might have to go for that option though if I find no better ones. Thanks for your reply.